# Sublime Text 2 file include pattern

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I know that a file exclude pattern can be set in Sublime Text's project/default settings, but is it also possible to only include files based on a pattern?

For example, when working with my C++ projects, I tend to have files in the same folder that are not necessarily source files.

Can I explicitly tell Sublime Text to show me only *.cpp, *.h, and *.txt files while ignoring everything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

List the extensions you want included in `file_include_patterns`. The following works for me with ST3 project files, don't have ST2 handy to test.

```
{
  "folders":
  [
    {
      "name": "My Project",
      "path": ".",
      "file_include_patterns": [
        "*.cpp",
        "*.h"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can confirm `file_include_patterns` works in ST2, but seems to be applied *before* `file_exclude_patterns`. Be careful if using both.

Comment: Make sure you close the file before you type ctrl-p to see if it is matched in the project folder. I kept finding it in ctrl-p no matter what until I closed it first. After that my include+exclude rules worked perfectly - matching it or not matching it.

Comment: where do you have to add this, in Preferences.sublime-settings? I can't save the settings file due to some syntax problem. Do I have to specify a project name?

Comment: @HermanToothrot This goes in the *<project-name>.sublime-project* file